# Upload file with ajax and formData

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload

I'm trying to upload a video to the Dailymotion API with ajax.

In my script i have :

```
                //upload the video and get the url
                var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', upload_url, true);
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
                xhr.send(formData);
```

My script is working but i have a problem, how can I specify which file field i want to use ?

If you see `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));`, `myForm` is the entire form, if my file input has `id="myInput"`, how can i specify that ?

I don't want to send all my form, but just one specific field.

Thanks !

Comment: Is it an `<input type="file"` ,if yes then you can use document.getElementById('myInput').files[0];

Answer (score 1):

This do what i want :

```
var file = document.getElementById("myInput").files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create en empty FormData and add the file value to it manually:

```
var file = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
```